# I can't iterate through duplicate values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, duplicates

the problem is with my list years, as you can see, some values are repeated like year 1932, 1933, 1961...:

```
years = [1924, 1928, 1932, 1932, 1933, 1933, 1935, 1938, 1953, 1955, 1961, 1961, 1967, 1969, 1971, 1977, 1979, 1980, 1988, 1989, 1992, 1998, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2007, 2007, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018]
```

So my duty is to make a function that iterate through all my lists (with len 34 all of them) BUT my output just return the dictionary with only one of the duplicated years so my resulting output it's 26 len instead of 34

```
def dictionary_maker2(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, list_update_damage, deaths):
    for n in range(len(years)):
        hurricanes_year[years[n]] = {'Names': names[n], 'Month': months[n], 'Year': years[n],
                                     'Max Sustained Wind': max_sustained_winds[n], 'Areas Affected': areas_affected[n],
                                     'Damage': list_update_damage[n], 'Deaths': deaths[n]}
```

Please, also let me know if i'm not using the correct way to asking the question in stackoverflow, this is my first question here.

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: Just to clarify what @Selcuk mentioned, since dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, when access a year value that you have already accessed and added value to the dictionary in previous iteration, it will overwrite the current value associated with that year with the new `{'Names': '', ...}` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The python dictionary can not have duplicate keys so, the last item in the iteration with same year overwrites the existing value. In this case you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
hurricanes_year = defaultdict(list)
def dictionary_maker2(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, list_update_damage, deaths):
    for n in range(len(years)):
        hurricanes_year[years[n]].append({'Names': names[n], 'Month': months[n], 'Year': years[n],
                             'Max Sustained Wind': max_sustained_winds[n], 'Areas Affected': areas_affected[n],
                            'Damage': list_update_damage[n], 'Deaths': deaths[n]})
```

If you want to iterate over all the years with all stored values

```
for hurricanes in hurricanes_year:
    for hurricane in hurricanes:
        print(hurricane)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, I don't think you can store duplicated year as a dictionary of sub-dictionaries associated with each year as each year can only store one hurricane data. To store multiple hurricanes data per year, I think you should set `hurricanes_year` as a dictionary that has years associated with a list (instead of a dictionary) containing a list of hurricanes data (dictionaries) of that year

```
def dictionary_maker2(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, list_update_damage, deaths):
    for n in range(len(years)):
        # Check if years[n] not exists in dictionary, if not then initialize empty list
        if years[n] not in hurricanes_year:
            hurricanes_year[years[n]] = []
        # Append hurricane data to the list associate with years[n]
        hurricanes_year[years[n]].append({'Names': names[n], 'Month': months[n], 'Year': years[n],
                                          'Max Sustained Wind': max_sustained_winds[n], 'Areas Affected': areas_affected[n],
                                          'Damage': list_update_damage[n], 'Deaths': deaths[n]})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true that dict, as a *hash-table* can't hold multiple values for the same key.

To workaround that, you could try to store in a dict a lists or records for each year and `append()` values instead of replacement.

```py
{<year>: [{<field>: <value>, ...}, ...], ...}
```

And FYI:

- you can use `zip()` to merge separate lists of values to a single list of tuples.
- tuple may be combined with dict keys the same way, that allows us to build dicts without naming every field

This may help to simplify the expression you have. For example:

```py
FIELD_NAMES = [
    'name', 
    'month', 
    'year', 
    'max_sustained_wind', 
    'area_affected', 
    'list_update_damage', 
    'deaths',
]

def columns_to_recors(*columns):
    # translate list of columns to a generator of dicts
    # like {<field>: <value>}
    return (dict(zip(FIELD_NAMES, values)) for values in zip(*columns))
    

def group_by_year(records):
    res = {}
    for rec in records:
        year = rec['year']
        group = res.setdefault(year, [])
        group.append(rec)
    return res

def print_groups(groups):
    print('Year\tRecords')
    for year, records in sorted(groups.items()):
        print(f'{year}\t{records}')

records = columns_to_records(*columns) # or (year, ..., smth_else)
groups = group_by_year(records) # {<year>: [{...}, {...}]}
print_groups(groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The trick is in the if-else statement. So, if my year is repeated, i append my values in the same key. So my final output will be like '1928key': [{1928values}], '1932key': [{1932values, 1932values}]

```
def create_year_dictionary(hurricanes):
hurricanes_by_year= dict()
for i in hurricanes:
    current_year = hurricanes[i]['Year']
    current_cane = hurricanes[i]
    if current_year not in hurricanes_by_year:
        hurricanes_by_year[current_year] = [current_cane]
    else:
        hurricanes_by_year[current_year].append(current_cane)
return hurricanes_by_year
```

print(create_year_dictionary(hurricanes))